# CMake error trying to link target to libraries

Tags: ros, target-link-libraries, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo.

I have created a pkg named "joy" in which there are two source file named `joystick.cpp` and `js_info.cpp` under `joy/src` folder. also i have header file `joystick.h` under `include/joy` folder.

i have compiled that 3 files and they work correctly.

But when i placed this files as told you above, gives me error as shown below:

```
CMake Error at joy/CMakeLists.txt:61 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "joystick" of type EXECUTABLE may not be linked into another target.
  One may link only to STATIC or SHARED libraries, or to executables with the
  ENABLE_EXPORTS property set.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/darshan/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/darshan/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

This below shown is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(joy)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
)
include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
add_executable(joystick src/joystick.cpp)
target_link_libraries(joystick ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(js_info src/js_info.cpp)
target_link_libraries(js_info ${catkin_LIBRARIES} joystick)
```

Please provide me the solution. I would be thankful to all of you.

---

Edit: Thank you so much for quick and prompt reply.

But if i change that line to

```
target_link_libraries(js_info ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
```

like this. I get the following error.

```
darshan@darshan-Inspiron-N4010:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/darshan/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/darshan/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/darshan/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/darshan/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/darshan/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/darshan/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/darshan/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_check_deps_Test
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RequestParam
Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RequestServiceInfo
Built target _rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_check_deps_Adc
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Log
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_TopicInfo
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RequestMessageInfo
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 13%] Built target abc
[ 13%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_Num
[ 13%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 13%] Built target _beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_check_deps_AddTwoInts
[ 13%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 15%] Built target hello
Linking CXX executable /home/darshan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/joy/joystick
[ 28%] Built target gui_ros
Linking CXX executable /home/darshan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/joy/js_info
[ 30%] Built target hello_world
[ 43%] Built target example
[ 46%] Built target rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_lisp
[ 47%] Built target turtle_teleop_joy
[ 53%] Built target rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_py
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 20 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 21 has invalid symbol index 22
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/darshan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/joy/joystick] Error 1
make[1]: *** [joy/CMakeFiles/joystick.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 56%] Built target rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_cpp
[ 63%] Built target rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
CMakeFiles/js_info.dir/src/js_info.cpp.o: In function `main':
js_info.cpp:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `Joystick::Joystick(char const*)'
js_info.cpp:(.text+0x204): undefined reference to `Joystick::getName()'
js_info.cpp:(.text+0x234): undefined reference to `Joystick::numAxes()'
js_info.cpp:(.text+0x274): undefined reference to `Joystick::numButtons()'
js_info.cpp:(.text+0x301): undefined reference to `Joystick::getAxis(int)'
js_info.cpp:(.text+0x339): undefined reference to `Joystick::getAxis(int)'
js_info.cpp:(.text+0x3c9): undefined reference to `Joystick::getButton(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/darshan/catkin_ws/devel/lib/joy/js_info] Error 1
make[1]: *** [joy/CMakeFiles/js_info.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
darshan@darshan-Inspiron-N4010:~/catkin_ws$.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223005/cmake-error-trying-to-link-target-to-libraries/) by [darshandoria](https://answers.ros.org/users/23601/darshandoria/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2015-12-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-23**:
May I suggest to change the title of your question? It has nothing to do with header files. Perhaps something like "CMake error trying to link target to libraries" is more appropriate.

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2015-12-23**:
Also, a ROS package with the name joy already exists. This will cause problems if you need both packages at the same time.

http://wiki.ros.org/joy

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-12-28**:
Please do not post answers to provide us with more information, *update* your question description for that, using the *edit* link/button below it. I've moved the contents of your answer this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error you get is actually quite clear, especially when you look at the following snippet from your `CMakeLists.txt`:

> ```
> add_executable(joystick src/joystick.cpp)
> ```

```
target_link_libraries(joystick ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

> ```
> add_executable(js_info src/js_info.cpp)
> ```

```
target_link_libraries(js_info ${catkin_LIBRARIES} joystick)
```

You are trying to link `js_info` against `catkin_LIBRARIES` (good) and against `joystick` (not good). That can't work: `joystick` is an executable, you just declared it 4 lines earlier with `add_executable(joystick src/joystick.cpp)`. You cannot link two executables together.

Also: this is really not ROS related, it's basic CMake and building of executables / binaries.

---

Edit:

> [..] if i change that line to

> ```
> target_link_libraries(js_info ${catkin_LIBRARIES} )
> ```

> like this. I get the following error:

> ```
> [..]
> CMakeFiles/js_info.dir/src/js_info.cpp.o: In function `main':
> ```

```
js_info.cpp:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `Joystick::Joystick(char const*)'
js_info.cpp:(.text+0x204): undefined reference to `Joystick::getName()'
js_info.cpp:(.text+0x234): undefined reference to `Joystick::numAxes()'
```

> ```
> [..]
> ```

This seems to indicate that the `js_info` target requires symbols from `joystick.cpp`. You could either:

- make the `joystick` target a library (`add_library(..)` instead of `add_executable(..)`) and link `js_info` against that, or
- add `joystick.cpp` to the list of source files for the `js_info` target

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [darshandoria](https://answers.ros.org/users/23601/darshandoria/) on 2015-12-28**:
Thank You so much sir, for your great help ! Made changes as suggested by you solved my problem.
Thank you once again.